# could not find driver error in lumen 5.6 app (running in docker + alpine linux + nginx + php-fpm 7.2)

Tags: php, docker, migration, lumen

I am trying to add database access to my Lumen 5.6 app, currently running in docker in the following LEMP Stack:

- Alpine Linux
- PHP-FPM 7.2.x
- NGINX

My compose file looks like this:

```
version: '2.1'

services:

  webhooks-mysql:
    container_name: webhooks-mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_DATABASE: webhooks
      MYSQL_USER: webhooks
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
    ports:
    - "33401:3306"

  webhooks-service:
    container_name: webhooks-service
    depends_on:
      webhooks-mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    build: .
    mem_limit: 64M
    ports:
      - "9050:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app:cached
```

and I have the following in my `.env`:

```
APP_NAME=webhooks
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:123456=
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=webhooks-mysql
DB_DATABASE=webhooks
DB_USERNAME=webhooks
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

and lastly; my container has all of the require dependencies:

```
php7 php7-fpm php7-mysqli php7-pdo php7-openssl php7-mbstring
php7-xml php7-tokenizer php7-json php7-openssl php7-curl php7-zlib 
php7-xml php7-phar php7-intl php7-dom php7-xmlreader php7-ctype 
php7-mbstring php7-gd php7-zip git nginx supervisor curl zip unzip
```

and the following composer packages:

```
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.6.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2",
    "wikimedia/ip-set": "^1.2",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.8"
  }
```

When I try to run the migration within the container, I am getting the following error:

> /app # php artisan migrate
>
> In Connection.php line 664:
>                                                                                                                              could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables
>   where table_schema = webhooks and table_name = )
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 50:
>                               could not find driver

Any ideas why I am getting this error?

I've already verified the php-mysql / pdo extensions are loaded, env values are correct etc... I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Since the docker image is completely stripped down there are more dependencies then you might expect, I encountered the same issue and fixed it by adding the extension `pdo_mysql` in addition to the ones you already have (`pdo`, `mysqli` and `mbstring`).

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue by using the following **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

# Install packages
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
 && apk add --update \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    git \
    zip \
    unzip \
    nano \
 && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer \
 && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Configure php-fpm
COPY scripts/fpm-pool.conf /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/zzz_custom.conf
COPY scripts/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zzz_custom.ini

# Add Application
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
```

Comment: This looks like the same solution as I suggested in my answer, might I ask why you post it as your own answer instead of accepting the solution?

Comment: Because I've shown how to properly do it for alpine & which command to use, i.e. `docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql `.